# Invoking print() with list.foreach in Scala is printing Nil

Tags: scala

I am a new to Scala and learning through the language constructs. While using print() with list.foreach() also prints the Nil or "()" in the console. Is this something expected or am I missing some trick here?

Code Snippet:

```
val oneTwo = "one"::"two"::Nil 
println(oneTwo.foreach(s=> print(s+" ")))
```

o/p: one two ()

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `println`.

```
oneTwo.foreach(s=> print(s+" "))
```

Prints the contents of the list - "one two".
The `println` you have outside prints out the return value of the `foreach` statement, which is `Unit` (not `Nil` - that's a completely different beast), represented in scala as `()`.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense and just to print the content I can directly use oneTwo.foreach(s=> print(s+" ").

Comment: Yeah. Or just `println(oneTwo.mkString(" "))`

Comment: This is great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To just output the list elements,

```
oneTwo.foreach(s=> print(s+" "))
```

would suffice. Now you put another print around that, so you say *"and then print whatever oneTwo.foreach(s=> print(s+" ")) evaluates to".*

The return type of foreach is [Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type), so it'll return the only value of that type, the empty tuple ().

So what you see is the list elements printed by the print in the foreach, and then the outer print prints the result of the foreach. Does that make sense?